# Populating collection view with Firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

This is my firebase realtime database structure:

[image]

I would like to populate a collectionView in my iOS app with all item keys that are under tree called "jogua-3b8fd".

The resulting collectionView items should be like this:

```
46-57-26

46-57-57

46-57-64

47-57-64

47-57-67

48-57-64

50-26-57

50-26-64

50-26-66

51-26-57

51-26-64

52-67

...
```

This is the way I am trying to get the data:

```
databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("jogua-3b8fd").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot.value as Any)
            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let shopName = valueDictionary["unique_id"]

                self.shops.insert(shopStruct(shopName: shopName), at: 0)

                self.mensajesCV.reloadData()
            }
        })
```

But is is showing an empty collectionView.

Comment: what is the `"unique_id"` ?

Comment: @emrcftci,  I don't know how to identify the key name for all the tree items

Comment: what is the output of `print(snapshot.value)` ? You should create a model that stores `[String]` to parse unique keys

Comment: @emrcftci, it is empty

Comment: remove the `.child("jogua-3b8fd")` and try again. `databaseRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in`

Comment: @emrcftci, doing as you say the output  shows all items of the database , but not the key name for the items below "jogua-3b8fd;

Comment: could you please try to `print(snapshot.key)` instead of `value`?

Comment: @emrcftci, thank you for your effort, but I will try to do it in another way. I will delete the question

Comment: if you found a new way to do it please share as an answer and mark as an accepted for others benefits

Comment: @emrcftci, not found yet, I will try another approach, thank you